# Conditional Response in Google Dialogflow-CX

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-cx, google-assistant

I have been trying to generate a conditional response for my intent.

[image]

As you can see, it is detecting my intent correctly and it is also detecting my parameter; but the conditional responses are not working somehow.

If someone can help me with where I am going wrong that will be appreciated

Comment: Hi! I had a lot of trouble with conditional responses as well. 
What worked for me was changing "intent" to "session": it was like conditional responses were only looking for session parameters sometimes. 
Also, your elifs are single-quoted, maybe try to fix that as well, and make sure to place an endif at the very end or it won't work.
Lastly, if you put a static fulfillment (text) and then a conditional response the second could be ignored maybe: remove the $intent.params.platform static response and try again perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that fixed it for me was adding .original or .resolved at the end of the parameter, e.g. $intent.params.platform.original. Strange that this should make a difference, but it does at least sometimes.

Comment: Didn't work. I had tried it. However, taking from the Session variable worked for me.